# Memcache with Symfony/Doctrine is reloading data

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, memcached

In my symfony project, I have a "complex" query that looks like:

```
$d = Doctrine_Core::getTable('MAIN_TABLE')
    // Create the base query with some keywords
->luceneSearch($keywords)
->innerJoin('w.T1 ws')
->innerJoin('ws.T2 s')
    ->innerJoin('w.T3 piv')
->innerJoin('piv.T4 per')
->innerJoin('w.T5 st')
    ...
->innerJoin('doc.T12 docT')
->innerJoin('w.Lang lng')
->execute();
```

I added all those innerJoin to reduce the number of query due to my data model. Actually all data are recovered with this only query.... but the query took from 2 to 20 sec. depends on keywords.

I decided to use memcache because data are not changing all the time.

What I've done is configuring memcache and adding

```
...
->useResultCache(true)
->execute();
```

to my query.

What is strange is that :

- The first time (when the cache is empty/flushed), only one query is execute
- The second time, ~130 ares executed and it take more time than the first...

Those "new" queries are retrieving data from "inner join" for each record.

What I don't undestand is why "innerjoined" data are not saved in the cache?

I tried to change the hydrate mode but it seems not to be influent.

Someone has an idea?

Comment: You should move your solution to an answer. Then you can accept your own answer. It's legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a whole day to googlise, to analyse doctrine and become desperate, I found an article that explain the solution:

```
class User extends BaseUser{
    public function serializeReferences($bool=null)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> The problem was the profile object was not getting stored in the result cache and thus causing a query each time it was called from the user object. After much hunting around, a long time in #doctrine, and a few leads from a couple of people, it turns out, by default, Doctrine will only serialize the immediate relation to the main object. However, you can make it so that it will serialize objects further down the line by overriding the function serializeReferences to return true in the class you want to serialize references from. In my example this is the User class. Since our application will never only need the ‘User’ class to be serialized on a result cache I completely overrode the function and made it always return true

http://shout.setfive.com/2010/04/28/using-doctrine-result-cache-with-two-deep-relations/